# Locked out of google cloud server

Tags: cloud

https://medium.com/@rubenszimbres/how-to-setup-a-sftp-server-in-google-cloud-platform-and-restrict-access-32a09b430c7d

I followed this tutorial but forgot to add myself to the restricted group, I am using google cloud VM, it will not let me in, citing an unexpected network error. Is there any way to get back in.

Just wondering if it is possible to get back in?